# labeling a group of members as private/public in c#

Tags: c#, class, declaration, private, members

in a c++ class declaration, you can label a group of members as private or public, e.g.

```
private:
  int x;
  double y;
```

seems like there's no way to do this in c#. am I wrong?

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't not do this in C#.

At best, you can use the default visibility for members, which is private, and not use private, but for public, you have to indicate it for all members.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. Although, if you leave visibility keyword off altogether, a member defaults to private.

Answer (score 1):

No you're not wrong. If you don't write any modifiers it will be assumed as private.

Comment: I believe that members without a visibility modifier will be implicitly made internal, not private.

Comment: Internal is default for classes and structures and for their members private is default.