# Declaring multiple public variables

Tags: c#, variables

```
public int var1;
public int var2;
public int var3;
```

Is there an easier way to declare multiple variables under one accessibility like this?

Something like

```
public:
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. Why? Is it too much typing?

Comment: Note that public variables should be avoided. You should use properties instead.

Comment: I have many variables in some classes and typing public behind every single one of them just seems really unnecessary. I thought I saw other languages have something like this.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546869/labeling-a-group-of-members-as-private-public-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Cains: Braces around single-statement `if` bodies are also technically unnecessary, but there is a very strong case to be made for using them. While C# doesn't go that far, requiring an explicit visibility specification before each member is a good thing, *especially* since definitions are always inline. Would you enjoy having to scroll two pages up to see what the visibility of a method is because it was unnecessary to type it on the spot? The designers thought you wouldn't, so they made this choice.

Comment: @Jon I see. I like to read my variables in sections of accessibility, as in my opinion scrolling to see what accessibility a section is is a lot easier than typing the accessibility for every variable.

Comment: @Cains: Well, I can't argue that your preference is wrong but do keep in mind that code is a write-once-read-many medium. You would save a little effort on typing (once) at the cost of a little effort on reading (many times).

Comment: @Jon I see your point, if others were reading my code it would be easier for them to understand it this way compared to the ease involved in me typing it that one time.

Comment: See this [Declaring and initializing multiple variables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517250/4287015)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it putting the accessibility first and all the variable names separated by a comma on the same line. Like this :

```
public int var1, var2, var3;
```

From your comment, it seems that you want the accessibility but different types. That is not possible, you would have to do it this way :

```
public int var1, var2;
public double var3;
```

Comment: Of course then they all have to share the same type.

Comment: @Jon I guess that is what the OP wanted, according to the example.

Comment: I apologize but the similar types were just coincidence. I'm looking for a solution that covers multiple types and preferably multiple lines.

Comment: @Tijesunimi It would still be a good idea to include it in your answer so it's more visible

Comment: @Cains you need to specify that in your question.And btw, what you are asking is **not possible**

Comment: @Tijesunimi: Sometimes we should use common sense on example code.

Comment: @Jon Yes. If he had given the type of example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546869/labeling-a-group-of-members-as-private-public-in-c-sharp). Then the question wouldn't have been misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int var1, var2, var3, var4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use all in a single line

> A single statement can assign multiple variables. Languages
>   derived from C-style syntax often allow you to use commas to declare
>   multiple variables in one statement.

```
 public int var1,var2,var3;
 public double d1,d2,d3;
 public string txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4;
```

Answer (score 1):

C# Doesn't support C++ syntax access specifier declaration.
The below programs shows how to declare multiple variables i C#

```
class MultipleVariable
{
    public int  x,y,z;
    private int x1,x2,x3;

    public float a,b,c;
    private float a1,b2,c3;

    public char p,q,r;
    private char p1,q2,r3;

};
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, and this class is useless... What are the advantages ?

Comment: Though the coding practice is unattractive, this DOES actually answer the question.

Comment: @payo It lacks the multiple types + the use of a class serves absolutely no purpose, it's just unnecessary overhead